# Running Multiple Stellar-core Instances on One Server

Tags: stellar-core, server

If your server quadruples the system requirements for running a Stellar-core node, can you run multiple instances of the software at the same time on one bare-metal machine?

If you use a NVME or PCIE SSDs for each instance, where would the bottlenecks be?

The reason for the question is that a 4U server can be more easily made and colocated than multiple 1Us or 2Us.